# Put values into a list inside SQL column Field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm looking to place a list of strings inside of a column field. I'm using the Concat function along with carriage return after each value.

CONCAT(column1.value, CHAR(13) + char(10), column2.value, CHAR(13) + char(10), column3.value3,CHAR(13) + char(10) as [Products]

This works ok if all of columns have a value.

```
PRODUCTS  
value1  
value2  
value3
```

however if there is no value in column1 the output will be

```
PRODUCTS  
--emptyline--  
value2  
value3
```

Im using case statements to check if each value is present. If its not is there anyway I can just output the values that are present and the carriage returns for the ones not present is not output

```
case when   
    len(CAST(column1.fieldValue as varchar)) > 0 then 'value1'  
end as value1
```

Comment: Surely UNPIVOT is a better way?

Comment: Sorry should have explained that the values need to be in the same field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+` to concatenate the column value with `CRLF` and use the `concat` function to concatenate the columns.

```
concat(Col1+char(13)+char(10),  Col2+char(13)+char(10))
```

Concatenating strings with `+` will make the entire result null if one part is null. Null values in the `concat` function is automatically converted to an empty string.